# How do I make a formula to find the dimensions of a shape that is offset from the original by 1/4 inch?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, triangles

I am trying to make a formula that given 3 lengths (left height, right height and base) it can give me new lengths of a shape that is 1/4" offset out from every side.

For example given this shape:
[example shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcbt7.png)

I need to find what the new dimensions would be for a similar shape that is off set 1/4" on every side like so:
[Offset shape by 1/4" in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQpiK.png)

I know for the base it will always be current base + 0.5". However left and right height change based off the slope.

Here is what I was trying to no avail, not sure if it is right:
[Attempt Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmMlN.png)
Left height = 30"
Right height = 10.5"
Base = 60"

[Attempt Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1UfD.png)
The easiest offset is for the Base as it is just adding 1/2"

Base = 60"+0.5"
Base = 60.5"

[Attempt Pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coD7B.png)
separate the triangle
a=Base
b=Left Height-Right Height
c= √(a²+b²)

a=60"
b=19.5"
c=63.08922253"

∠bc=tan^-1(a/b)
∠bc=tan^-1(60"/19.5")
∠bc=72°

[Attempt Pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANDpu.png)
Next is finding the radius of the inscribed circle:

r= (ab/a+b+c)
r= ((60")(19.5")/60"+19.5"+63.08922253")
r= 8.205388733"

Next is the radius of the offset circle:

r=8.205388733"+.25
r=8.455388733"

The ratio between the two radius is:

1.030467783

After I got that far I used the ratio x the triangle lengths to get the offset triangle however when I tried to add it back to the original shape it kept coming out with the wrong dimensions.

I don't know if what I am doing makes sense but this is where I am stuck.

After I figure out an equation for this shape I will then need to make one for this type to, however it has one extra dimensions which is left inset.
[Other shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXFt.png)

Comment: Depends on the original size. Use similarity and equate ratios of the sides.

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  Assume that the new base length is fixed as old base $+ (0.5)$, and that the new left side is fixed as old left side $ + (0.25)$.  You then have two mutually exclusive choices: [1] You can assume that the new slope equals the old slope, and recalculate the right side, based on that. [2] You can assume that the new right side equals the old right side $+ (0.25)$ and recalculate the slope, based on that.

Comment: What you have is a shape defined by four lines (five in the case of the "Other shape") that you want to "offset" by some amount.  In other words, you need the to know the final shape as defined by the new "offset" lines.  That'll mean that you're doing a bit more than just "adding on" to the starting height of your old corner... as you'll actually have to "extend the line" out all the way to the new corner.  I'll try to elaborate more in an answer when I'm not on my lunch break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the above figure you can see that the length that has to be deducted from

the original (black) sides at the intersection is

$ a = t \cot(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) $

where $\theta $ is the angle between the two black sides.

So, with the given example, the sides are: $30, 60, 10.5, \sqrt{19.5^2 + 60^2} $.  The bottom angles are $90^\circ$ each, while the top left is $\theta^* = \tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{60}{19.5} \right) \approx 72^\circ$

Hence, using the above calculation, the bottom side will be reduced by $2 \times 0.25'' $ , the left side will be reduced by $0.25'' + 0.25'' \times \cot(36^\circ) = 0.594'' $, and the right side will be reduced by $0.25'' + 0.25'' \cot(0.5(180 - 72)^\circ ) = 0.431''$, and finally the top side will be reduced by $0.25'' (\cot(36^\circ) + \cot(54^\circ) ) = 0.526'' $

Hence the sides of the new shape are

Bottom:  $60'' - 0.5'' = 59.5''$

Left Height: $30'' - 0.594'' = 29.406''$

Right Height: $10.5'' - 0.431'' = 10.069''$

Top Side:  $\sqrt{60^2 + 19.5^2} - 0.526'' = 62.563''$

Comment: I am a little confused on what you mean I am trying to offset the new shape to the outside by 1/4" so why am I deducting? Sorry if I am misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: See the picture. This picture shows top left corner of the shape. Orange is original shape.  $t$ is offset. $a$ is increase of left side of original shape. You can use the same approach to find increase of right side of original shape. Increase of top side is sum of increase of left and right sides. Increase of bottom side is $2t$.

Comment: I think I understand, trying it know thank you.

Comment: Please check my updated solution.  If you have further questions, I'll be happy to explain further.